# Question about Compare with String and Integer. CS50 Pset 4

Tags: string, integer, cs50

I am studying CS50 Pset 4.

As I know, I type the same word eg: "Emma". When I compare them, they will not the same coz they are storing it in 2 different addresses in the memory.

But I am confused about integer, they are also storing in 2 different addresses in the memory even I input the same number. But they are the same when I compare them.

Can someone tell me what I misunderstood?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = get_int("i: ");
    int j = get_int("j: ");

    char *s = get_string("s: ");
    char *t = get_string("t: ");

    if (i == j)
    {
        printf("Same\n");
        printf("%p\n", &i);
        printf("%p\n", &j);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Different\n");
        printf("%p\n", &i);
        printf("%p\n", &j);
    }

     if (s == t)
    {
        printf("Same\n");
        printf("%p\n", &s);
        printf("%p\n", &t);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Different\n");
        printf("%p\n", &s);
        printf("%p\n", &t);
    }
}
```

Comment: `==` always compares the values but pointer values are numbers that represent the memory addresses while integer values are just the integers without any indirection or memory location.

Comment: So you mean string actually is pointer values? But integers isn't?

Comment: Not really, a `char *` (known as a string if it's null terminated) is a pointer to the first character of the string. Its value is a numerical memory location (print it and see, `printf("%p\n", s)`). An integer is also a numerical value that is literally its own value. Use `strcmp` if you want to compare the values of strings, not the memory locations.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two strings using `==`. In order to do so sucessfully, you either use a function called `strcmp`, or create a loop iterating over all characters in the string. (include `#include <string.h>` in order to make this work. This is what your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = get_int("i: ");
    int j = get_int("j: ");

    char *s = get_string("s: ");
    char *t = get_string("t: ");

    if (i == j)
    {
        printf("Same\n");
        printf("%p\n", &i);
        printf("%p\n", &j);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Different\n");
        printf("%p\n", &i);
        printf("%p\n", &j);
    }

     if (strcmp(s, t) == 0)
    {
        printf("Same\n");
        printf("%p\n", &s);
        printf("%p\n", &t);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Different\n");
        printf("%p\n", &s);
        printf("%p\n", &t);
    }
}
```

`strcmp` takes input two string, and outputs `0` if they're the same, and any other number if not. (Hope this helps!!:))